# Find missing dates and print the record [PostgresSQL]

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a table with two columns ID and Date say like with below data. For a given range say like from 2022-09-01 to 2022-09-10 I want to return the missing dates for respective ID's along with ID value, I want data to be returned as mentioned in Expected output. How can I achieve this

**Data inside table:**

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-01 |
| 1 | 2022-09-07 |
| 1 | 2022-09-08 |
| 1 | 2022-09-09 |
| 2 | 2022-09-01 |
| 2 | 2022-09-02 |
| 2 | 2022-09-03 |
| 2 | 2022-09-04 |

**Expected Output:**

| ID | Missing Dates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-02 |
| 1 | 2022-09-03 |
| 1 | 2022-09-04 |
| 1 | 2022-09-05 |
| 1 | 2022-09-06 |
| 1 | 2022-09-10 |
| 2 | 2022-09-05 |
| 2 | 2022-09-06 |
| 2 | 2022-09-07 |
| 2 | 2022-09-08 |
| 2 | 2022-09-09 |
| 2 | 2022-09-10 |

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could write a stored procedure or function to return such a result set. For ex. you can get the min and max ID and loop thru them to build your result rows in a TABLE variable, and at the end of your loop, list all the rows in your TABLE var.

Comment: I am trying through SQL Queries as I need to use query in my application, with query I can get missing dates but not the ID values as I can do a not in from a calendar table to this table, but not getting expected output.

select date_cal as Missing_Dates from "Main_calendar" where date_cal>='2022-01-01' and date_cal<='2022-01-10'
and TO_CHAR(date_cal,'YYYY-MM-DD') not in(
select TO_CHAR(date_time,'YYYY-MM-DD') as date_cal
from "Main" where date_time>='2022-09-01' and date_time<='2022-10-10')

Comment: If you can prepare a table with the date range you are interested in and have row for all the IDs, then you could use `OUTER JOIN` to get the missing rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote sample query for you:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id int4 NULL,
    pdate date NULL
);

INSERT INTO test1 (id, pdate) VALUES(1, '2022-09-01');
INSERT INTO test1 (id, pdate) VALUES(1, '2022-09-07');
INSERT INTO test1 (id, pdate) VALUES(1, '2022-09-08');
INSERT INTO test1 (id, pdate) VALUES(1, '2022-09-09');
INSERT INTO test1 (id, pdate) VALUES(2, '2022-09-01');
INSERT INTO test1 (id, pdate) VALUES(2, '2022-09-02');
INSERT INTO test1 (id, pdate) VALUES(2, '2022-09-03');
INSERT INTO test1 (id, pdate) VALUES(2, '2022-09-04');


select t1.id, t1.datelist from (
    select t.id, generate_series(t.startdate, t.enddate, '1 day')::date as datelist from (
        select distinct id, '2022-09-01'::date as startdate, '2022-09-10'::date as enddate from test1 
    ) t 
) t1 
left join test1 t2 on t2.pdate = t1.datelist and t1.id = t2.id 
where t2.pdate is null 


Result: 

id  datelist
1   2022-09-02
1   2022-09-03
1   2022-09-04
1   2022-09-05
1   2022-09-06
1   2022-09-10
2   2022-09-05
2   2022-09-06
2   2022-09-07
2   2022-09-08
2   2022-09-09
2   2022-09-10
```